# I can't alter the width of an item through CSS

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm a beginner in front-end development and I'm working on a survey website.  My website has a lot of input fields and I want to alter their width per their nature but I'm not able to do it for some reason.  The item is not in a flex container and yet changing the value in the `width` attribute makes no difference.

I'm trying to change the width of my `input` field in my `customerAge` div to make it small enough to just hold 2 digits.

This is my codepen link: https://codepen.io/omaroz92/full/VBWbae/

I'd appreciate a detailed explanation on why changing the value in the width attribute made no difference.

```css
body {
  background-color: #98AFC7;
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Times, serif;
  font-style: oblique;
  color: white;
}

#screen-belly {
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 75%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace, serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.container {
  width: 75%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.customerAge {
  width: 100px;
}

input {
  flex: 1;
  height: 20px;
  min-width: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Survey Form</h1>

<div id="screen-belly">
  <p>Please take the short Survey to hep us improve our services</p>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <input autofocus type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="First name" required>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="e-Mail address" required>
    </div>

    <div class="customerAge">
      <input type="number" name="age" id="Age" placeholder="age" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try to add ```customerAge``` class to input, not to ```div```

Comment: try to remove code that are unrelated to the issue. Isolate the problem a bit for the readers

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've wrapped the `Age` input in `customerAge` div. But you've applied the `width` property to the parent, not to the `input`.
You can try this in your css code:

```
.customerAge input#Age {

    width: 31px;
}
```

And you can change `31px` to the value you want.

If you are confused, the `input#Age` after `.customerAge`, means: the `input` field with `Age` id that is inside of the `customerAge` class.